What is this usage of "and not", if correct?
What is the usage of "not all" in the following quote from StarCraft:

I'm pretty much the Queen Bitch of the Universe. And not all of your little soldiers or space ships will stand in my way again.

Here, "not all" is used as in "none". But without context, many would read the last sentence as meaning:

And some of your little soldiers or space ships will stand in my way again.

which is arguably not the intention of the writers.
Is that an oversight by the script writer, or is there some (obscure) usage of "not all"?

How do you know that “none” is meant?

It is an established usage, probably intended here to suggest old-fashioned heroic language. The sense is "even your whole army will not be enough to stand in my way". Admittedly, it does sound ambiguous to the modern audience.
An Ngram of not all the might finds expressions like Not all the might and power of imperial Rome could uproot and destroy it, and Not all the might of Lochlin shall resist the sword That shall be brandish'd in  her righteous cause.

This is not that Roman example at all. Not all the little soldiers will etc. BUT not: Not all of your little soldiers. Humpty Dumpt: Not all the King's men etc.

"intended here to suggest old-fashioned heroic language", but in fact I'd call it "mock-heroic" - not quite "accurate". Apart from anything else, the negation is in the wrong place. It should be: And all of your little soldiers or space ships will not stand in my way again.

@FumbleFingers - Surely the sense is "Nothing - not even [a powerful force] - can stop me." But I agree that the dialogue in the film (sorry, game) uses it clumsily.

Well, in all fairness, it's not supposed to be "convincing". Your example with Not all the might and power of imperial Rome... feels authentic - not least because of hifalutin words like might and imperial. The cited text is supposed to be facetious, as already flagged up by preceding "lofalutin" pretty much and Queen Bitch.
